# Influxdb howto update tag values

Tags: tags, influxdb

I would like to do a query like this:

```
SELECT max(value) as value, "counter" = 'countergasconsumption'
INTO "home"."1month"."test"
FROM "telegraf"."autogen"."mqtt_consumer"
WHERE time > now() - 11d AND "topic" = '/utilitiesmonitor/countergasconsumption'
GROUP BY time(5m)
```

I already have data with the countergasconsumption tag (not the whole topic). I can't get it to work, tried different select into's and the docs are not really helpful on this topic. The old data is one measurement with a tag for the type of counter, the new data comes in on separate topics via Telegraf.

Comment: I don't follow what you expect `"counter" = 'countergasconsumption'` in the body of a select statement to do. Can you clarify what the expected result of this is.

Comment: I'm getting data from the mqtt_consumer measurement and I want to insert it in another but with a tag key "counter" and tag value "countergasconsumption"

Comment: Are you using Telegraf?